# Create Conditional Tasks in Airflow

Tags: python, airflow

I  am new in air flow and 2 days ago I  decided to use it with my system , this is the explaination of what I  am trying to  do

I  have ISP  system  where  users connected to  the internet with specific  Bandwidth let's says it is 20Mbps  , I  have peak time where all  customers connected and causing load on the network ,  what  I  want is  create  policies where I  can define the peak start/end time ,   in airflow ,  I  need to fetch all  the policies and check  the start/endtime  if the time is between them then I  need to  decrease  the bandwidth  ,  by execute decrease_bandwidth function only one time  , so  suppose the  peak time is
[09:00,13:00] so if the time between  9 and 13 I  need  to  send  the  decrease command which must run only one time  so I  don't want to  keep  send that command every  time between the peak time , in the  other hand if  thetime is  13:00 I  so  that  mean the peak  time is finished so I  need  to  return the customers back to  there own  speed ,  again only one time  , so  how  can I achieve that , I  have this code

```
from __future__ import annotations
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator
from airflow.operators.datetime import BranchDateTimeOperator
from airflow.operators.empty import EmptyOperator
import pendulum
# Define the function to fetch policies from the database
def fetch_policies():
    # Example code to fetch policies from the database
    policies = [
        {'id': 1, 'start_time': '06:00', 'end_time': '18:00'}
    ]
    return policies

# Define the function to decrease bandwidth
def decrease_bandwidth(policy_id):
    # Your code to decrease bandwidth goes here
    print(f"Decreasing bandwidth for policy {policy_id}.")

# Define the function to return bandwidth to normal
def return_to_normal_bandwidth(policy_id):
    # Your code to return bandwidth to normal goes here
    print(f"Returning bandwidth to normal for policy {policy_id}.")

# Define the DAG
default_args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'start_date': datetime(2024, 2, 22),  # Start date of the DAG
    'email': ['airflow@example.com'],
    'email_on_failure': False,
    'email_on_retry': False,
    'retries': 1,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=5),
}
dag2 = DAG(
    dag_id="Check_Policy_time",
    start_date=pendulum.datetime(2021, 1, 1, tz="Europe/Istanbul"),
    catchup=False,
    tags=["example"],
    schedule="@daily",
)
empty_task_12 = EmptyOperator(task_id="date_in_range", dag=dag2)
empty_task_22 = EmptyOperator(task_id="date_outside_range", dag=dag2)

cond2 = BranchDateTimeOperator(
    task_id="datetime_branch",
    follow_task_ids_if_true=["date_in_range"],
    follow_task_ids_if_false=["date_outside_range"],
    target_upper=pendulum.time(21, 0, 0),
    target_lower=pendulum.time(13, 0, 0),
    dag=dag2,
)

cond2 >> [empty_task_12, empty_task_22]
```

as you see  in this code  I  am checking if the condition is right  I  am running one of the tasks , but  how can  I  be sure if  the   task has been  runned so  no need to  run it again , and  how  can  I  create dynamically  schedule  the task2  where I  need to  return the bandwidth to  it's normal  state , one time . I  hope I  explained  my issue clearly ,
I  want to  run the task1  at 09:00  and I  want to  run the  task2  at 13:00 both of them for only one time and sure if it is success  ,  if it is  failed so  it is ok  I  need to  run  it again

Comment: Can you write 2 scheduled DAGs: the 1st one decrease_bandwidth starts every day at the beginning of your peak time (9:00) and and the 2nd one increase_bandwidth starts at end of peak time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I got it, what you need are two DAGs with one task each to do the job.
Assuming your example with 9-13h peak:

- DAG 1, scheduled to run 9am, with decrease_bandwidth task; and
- DAG 2, scheduled to run 1pm, with return_to_normal_bandwidth task.

With this strategy, both dags/tasks would run once.